# Why is there the need to disable input validation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Why does the IIS pipeline in ASP.NET require you to opt-out of input validation? As far as I know, with all other major web development frameworks, you can post whatever you like in a form. When rendering templates in the default manner, those values will be automatically HTML encoded to prevent security vulnerabilities.

ASP.NET has the same features. If I were to disable input validation on a specific controller action, and then render the result with the defaults (not using `Html.Raw`), it will automatically be HTML encoded. In the same way as other web frameworks, I can opt out of the automatic HTML encoding in the template by using `Html.Raw`. However, if I submit a value in a form that contains angle brackets, *without* disabling input validation, then I receive the `A potentially dangerous value was detected from the client` error.

Since the chances are that any arbitrary form will allow the user to use things like angle brackets, then why is this security feature on by default? It seems like it doesn't help anything, and just gets in the way by forcing the developer to disable it manually.

Am I misunderstanding something about this, or is disabling input validation for the majority (if not all) of forms very common in the ASP.NET world?

Comment: Considering that this feature has been in ASP.NET for a decade, and that you apparently have not been using ASP.NET for a decade, which of the two of you is more likely to be misunderstanding something?

Comment: I have actually been using ASP.NET for a while now, but I have always disabled request validation and HTML encoded the values in any templates that render it. This question was more about the *why* I needed to disable it, or if I was missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Request validation was originally created many years ago when reflective XSS was rampant on the web. At the time the ASP.NET team believed that it could offer a good in-box protection mechanism against this attack by rejecting requests that were likely to contain reflective XSS markup.

Hindsight is 20/20, and in retrospect this was a terrible idea because it lulls developers into a false sense of security. Request validation is very leaky; it does a poor job of shutting these down. And as you've already stated, encoding these values appropriately on the output (as our later frameworks do) is much preferred to rejecting input.

The ASP.NET team has officially disowned request validation as a protection mechanism, and we're not making any more changes to it, even if somebody is able to break it wholesale. But we must leave it on by default due to the number of applications which for better or for worse rely on it. We're considering ways to make disabling it far easier in an upcoming update.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#validation

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense. I was more worried that I did not understand a possibly attack vector. You have assuaged my fears.